# Can we use Panels for Responsive web design?

Tags: panels, theming

I would like to make a new site using responsive design using the Omega theme.
Are panels modules suitable for responsive design or should I use something else(like the Context module)?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two new ways of doing responsive design in Panels include [Adaptivetheme 3.x](http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) and the [Panoply](http://drupal.org/project/panopoly) distribution.

Answer (score 5):

Yes! I just did it.

Assuming 2 col and variants - you might need more for other layouts:

1. In the lowest resolution @media query CSS I just set the '.panels-col-first' and '.panels-col-last' to `{ width: 99.9%; clear: both }`.
2. In higher resolution layouts, when you want it to go back to 2-col layout just undo the override `{ width: 49.9%; clear: none }`

Notes:

- the % widths should add up to LESS than 100% if you want to support IE 6 and 7 as they have rounding errors. You can always do this in your special ie.css if you have one and really need that 0.2% back!
- These classes should already be set to float left by the main Panels CSS, but you can override that too if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. No need to code in css to resolve the problem. 
--> Omega handle well panels in responsive design.

> "Omega comes with a handful of panels layouts by default. If you enable
>   Panels on your site with the Omega theme also enabled, and you go to
>   add a new panel you will see Omega: 12, ( or 16 or 24) Column Grid
>   listed. Choose one of those, then choose a layout. I'm embarrassed
>   about how easy it was, and I never even knew!"

I found the solution on this page, second comment 
http://www.kendallsdesign.com/blog/omega-theme-responsive-design-resources

By the way, there is really good materials.